# How to run Java autotests from TestRail

Tags: java, testrail

The all that I've found about integration of autotests and TestRail is that Java TestRail API can update test results in TestRail. But I want to have integration in both ways. I want to run Java autotests from TestRail. Is there such possibility ?

Please share links, articles.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your correctly, To implement a system to directly trigger tests from TestRail using a combination of a UI script and custom server-side scripts.

https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/customization/automation-trigger

The UI script adds a new button to the toolbar for test runs. When clicked it sends an HTTP request to the server-side script which in turn triggers the automated tests. The script or tests then report back the test results via TestRail’s API.

Github link:
https://github.com/gurock/testrail-custom/tree/master/automation/trigger-run-example/4.x